# Pydantic dataclass with Field alias triggers pylint E1123 unexpected-keyword-arg

Tags: python, pylint, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I'm using the [dataclasses feature](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/dataclasses/) in Pydantic v2.3.0 and I have a dataclass with an aliased field, like so:

```py
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Example:
    number: int = Field(alias='n')


example = Example(n=5)
```

This is valid code and runs just fine, but pylint triggers the following warning:

`E1123: Unexpected keyword argument 'n' in constructor call (unexpected-keyword-arg)`

Is this a pylint bug? A pydantic bug? Expected behavior?

Does anyone have a good workaround to either...

- help pylint recognize that `n` is a valid constructor argument, or
- silence this warning for the `Example` class?

I'm aware that I could globally silence `E1123(unexpected-keyword-arg)` but I'd rather just suppress this false-positive case.

For reference:

```
$ pylint --version
pylint 2.17.5
astroid 2.15.6
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0]
```